# How can I show the next 3, 6, 9, etc. children when clicking an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 9 items, and I only want to display 3 at a time. When I click the next button, it shows the next three items (4,5,6) and when I click it another time it should show the next three items from that (7,8,9) and so on, for any count. Once it reaches the end and you click the "next" button again, it should show the first 3 elements again (1,2,3) and start over from there.

How can this be achieved?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
  $(this).parent().find("ul").children().slice(0, 6).animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="next">Next</div>

  <ul>
    <li>Hello 1</li>
    <li>Hello 2</li>
    <li>Hello 3</li>
    <li>Hello 4</li>
    <li>Hello 5</li>
    <li>Hello 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: Use a class name to keep track of the elements being displayed, each time the button is clicked find the last one and display the next three. Or keep the first index in a global variable, increment it each time the button is clicked and then do `slice(index,index+3)`. Of course you should add a line to check if the index is past the last element, to take it back to 0.

Comment: Good idea @Gabriel , I solved it. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class name to keep track of the elements being displayed, each time the button is clicked find the last one and display the next three.

Or keep the first index in a global variable, increment it each time the button is clicked and then do slice(index,index+3).

Of course you should add a line to check if the index is past the last element, to take it back to 0.